# Хешировать пароль в MongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Нужно чтобы при выполнении `POST` запроса, пароль сохранять в базе как хешированый. Как это сделать? Вот сам `POST`:

```
@PostMapping("api/names/users")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createPerson(@RequestBody Person newPerson) {
        logger.info("Success_Post");
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(personRepository.save(newPerson), HttpStatus.OK);
```

А вот и класс `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;

private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String old;
(geters and setters)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось сделать это достаточно просто. Нужно всего лишь добавить `import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;`. Затем использовать `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. В целом, это выглядит так:

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
@PostMapping("api/names/users")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createPerson(@RequestBody Person newPerson) {
        logger.info("Success_Post");
        newPerson.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPerson.getPassword()));
        logger.debug("POSTing person" + newPerson );
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(personRepository.save(newPerson), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```